# How to expand the size of the root partition

Tags: partitioning

I want to expand the root partition by 10 GB, how can I do this?[attached a photo of my sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkem5.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 reached the end of Community Support in 2019. We no longer answer questions about it. Consider migrating to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Back up all data first. Second backup all data.  From a USB move partition 4 to the right.  This should leave 10GBs beside partition 3.  Add space to partition 3.  Recover data from backups.